# How to fix problem with 'getColor' getting every car being green?

Tags: sumo

I'm making a program that makes the cars running in the simulation pass on their colors to other cars, to achieve that I'm using the TraCi function `'getColor'`. The problem is that every car that I ask the color returns (255,255,0,255) doesn't matter what the actual color is. However, using `'getColor'` inside a condition for the "contamination" makes the program work, maybe out of sheer luck. Please help me understand how to fix it and how it works.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, SUMO 0.32.0 and using the `traci` library. I've tried modifying the program and running the simulation step by step, even running the same line in different code with the same idea in mind.

This is the program in which the "contamination" works although it gets the wrong colors:

```
def run():
    step = 0
    while traci.simulation.getMinExpectedNumber() > 0:
        traci.simulationStep()
        step += 1  
        if step > 2:
            if distancia("veh1","veh0") < 5:
                traci.vehicle.setColor("veh1",(255,0,0,255))
            if distancia("veh0","veh2") < 5 :
                traci.vehicle.setColor("veh2",(255,0,0,255))
            if traci.vehicle.getColor("veh2") == (255,0,0,255):
                if distancia("veh1","veh2") < 5 :
                    traci.vehicle.setColor("veh1",(255,0,0,255))
            print(traci.vehicle.getColor("veh1"))
    traci.close()
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I hoped when I selected the red car I would get (255,0,0,255), but I got (255,255,0,0). But it doesn't get any error messages, just shows the worng color.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the default color for traci is yellow, I'd to set every car to its own color from the python code to start doing what I wanted.